# How to efficiently group by date with a timezone specified?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, azure-sql-database

I'm currently running an aggregate query, summing amounts sold (say) on a given date.

```
select convert(date, datetimesold), sum(amountsold) from tblSold 
group by convert(date, datetimesold)
```

where datetimesold is a datetime value.

The `convert(date,...)` gets rid of the time value, so the `group by` can group by whole day.

Already this isn't efficient, as it requires a table scan for the convert per row - a better approach would be to add a 'datesold' column containing just the date value, indexed, and include this value on insert each time. But this would lose precision on that column, and that is important, because...

`datetimesold` is a UTC datetime. So my question is: say I wanted to group by day, but on Eastern US time. I would have to add an offset in hours to datetimesold before doing the convert in the group by - `group by convert(date, dateadd(hours, -5, datetimesold))` - but even then this wouldn't be always accurate due to daylight savings - EDT -4 hours, EST -5 hours.

Do I have any efficient options to do this in SQL? Are there any timezone-aware functions that I can use here?

EDIT: To further clarify, I'm operating on Azure SQL databases.

Comment: " a better approach would be to add a 'datesold' column containing just the date value " cast to date is sargable,so it can use index if present ..If I get it right what you mean

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already noticed that it is difficult to convert from UTC to local time zone correctly. In fact, it is very difficult, because rules for daylight savings change. You need to maintain a historical database of timezones to do it properly.

I store two timestamps - in UTC and in local time zone. In some reports we need UTC, in some local.

Usually it is easy to convert between UTC and local time zone when the row is inserted and the OS of the client computer, which generates the data is in correct local time zone. At that moment OS knows both local and UTC time. But, if you have historical data from previous years it becomes much more difficult to perform such conversion.

SQL Server 2016 promises to add somewhat better support for time zones, see: [AT TIME ZONE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx).

---

As for your concern about table scan - you'll always have to scan the whole table to calculate the `SUM`, so extra `CONVERT`  to `date` doesn't really matter.

On the other hand,

If you have a separate column that stores just `date`, not `datetime`, the query will be a bit more efficient, because `date` takes less bytes than `datetime`, so less bytes to read from disk.

If you add an index on `(datesold, amountsold)`, then the `GROUP BY` would not have to do an extra sort, which also makes a query more efficient.

---

So, in the current version of SQL Server I'd add an indexed `date` column which would contain a date in the time zone that you need for your reports. If there is a need for reports in UTC and Eastern US time zones, I'd add two separate `date` columns.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir - good point regarding the table scan cost. Your solution using an extra column is what I feared might be the only possibility - unfortunately this can't be made into a generic feature unless we scale up to n columns where n is the number of timezones we envisage supporting. I may end up doing it anyway! Good idea re. just using a date datatype anyway.

Comment: Well, Azure should have that `AT TIME ZONE` feature already - check it out. You should check how it works for historical dates, though, if it is relevant for you. I don't know if it is deterministic in the sense that it is possible to create a computed and persisted column with it. You can end up with having several persisted columns for the most common timezones and for all other time zones do the calculations on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the timezone name somehow, you can use the variant of the SQL date function that accepts a standard timezone string e.g.

```
select
    date(date, @timezone_name) as dte, sum(amountsold) from tblSold 
    group by dte
```

where `@timezone_name` is any value from:

```
select * from sys.time_zone_info
```

(SQL 2016+)

Answer (score -1):

try with Cast the values to a Date type for your group by.

GROUP BY CAST(myDateTime AS DATE)

to manage timezone , you can use .net api nodatime and  make it CLR SQL function ,would be help to resolve UTC datetime issue.

http://nodatime.org/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sameer. Unfortunately (as I've just edited the question) CLR stored procedures are not an option for me, as my databases are on the Azure platform, and thus support for CLR is very limited, as I understand it. Plus I would have to also include the NodaTime assemblies.

Comment: Also I was hoping there might be some native SQL support - looks like not! 

One other thing: you suggest CAST rather than my CONVERT - I don't think there's any difference between the two given what I'm doing. CONVERT is T-SQL specific, I guess.

(+1 to you for a Jon Skeet reference, anyway :) )

Comment: @Sameer Morani -1, as your answer is quite unclear and doesn't answer the question well (as it currently reads)